# Navigation device with offline maps and GPX support

Tags: navigation, maps, gps

I have a subscription service from komoot for maps. Is there any GPS device that supports offline maps and GPX, preferably with android OS integration. Example scenario would be: Use an android based GPS apps in that Navigation device. Basically, I would like to avoid using my android phone for navigation, while hiking big trails.

Comment: Simplest option is to get a second phone and use that for navigation

Comment: Quickly reading, seems that GPX can be converted to other supported formats, so you can get your route GPX and convert and upload it to the device of choice. I'd have a look at a device you like, then see what files it supports. Garmin can support GPX via it's Basecamp software, for example, but is not Android based.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a gps device with maps that does not support gpx? Well in any case even if there is, gpsbabel will come to your rescue.

Comment: Possibly a question for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A lot of Garmin GPSs have offline mapping built in and communicate with your phone to upload GPX files. Other brands do too, at least in their bike computers. Almost all of what you ask for is common, the exception being the OS your dedicated GPS runs

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at an application called Avenza PDF Maps.  Avenza allows you to download a host of free (can not free) maps onto your tablet or smart phone.  Since Avenza is displaying the map background and your location on the map only using the device and the devices GNSS you do not need cellular coverage to see your location.  If you are in the USA you can download any USGS topographic map for free.  GPX support?  This is planed for a future Avanza release.  You could bring your GPX data into something like QGIS and create your own geo-spatial PDFs.  If that is the case have a look at GIS Stackexchange for help there.

If you need more GPX support consider BackcountryNavigator which allows you to download data for off-grid use and import GPX files.

Answer (score 1):

Gaia GPS and Trailforks both have gpx support and free offline maps. [trailforkes is great if your hiking areas are near biking trails].

Avenza is great as well, but takes more setting up. If you want to make custom maps and layers this is your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am  using [Oruxmaps](https://oruxmaps.com/cs/en/). Great program, open source. Can load USGS geo pdfs, Garmin maps, KML, CSV and also gpx.